# Upgrading to Flutter 2.0 breaks flutter firebase web project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I had a full working project and updated flutter to 2.0 and also the full project to null safety.

Now the very first and basic step of getting data from firebase is not working for web.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
appState = AppState.loading;
loadData();
}

void loadData() async {
QuerySnapshot val = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(FirestoreFields.APPDATA_COLLECTION)
    .get();
setState(() {
  if (val.docs.length == 0)
    appState = AppState.databaseSetupPending;
  else
    appState = AppState.databaseDownloading;
});
}
```

This code give me following error on flutter for web.

```
Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Expected a value of type '((Object?) => Object)?', but got one of type '(Object) => Object?'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:5032:11)
    at collection_reference_web.CollectionReferenceWeb.new.get (http://localhost:60662/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:370:23)
    at get.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:37210:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:37081:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:32337:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:32864:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:32902:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:32750:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:32771:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:37333:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:37339:13)
    at http://localhost:60662/dart_sdk.js:33110:9
```

But same projects runs perfectly on my android device.

All my other projects which dont use firebase are also running perfectly on web after updating and making them null safe.

This is my index.html file:

```
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "*******************************",
      authDomain: "*******************************",
      projectId: "*******************************",
      storageBucket: "*******************************",
      messagingSenderId: "*******************************",
      appId: "**************************************************************",
      measurementId: "*******************************"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello, I recommend you check the following link [Migration Guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/) it will help you to check if you upgraded to the latest recommended versions which are stable versions. It is important to check this because normally you have to wait to use a certain new version because it could have certains things that need to be fixed. If you still have problems after checking that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

To see a full list of available changes, run the following command:

```
dart fix --dry-run
```

To apply all changes in bulk, run the following command:

```
dart fix --apply
```

check the docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix

Comment: dart fix --dry-run and dart fix --apply give a same message. "Nothing to fix!"